# Jetbrains rider fails to run azure function project, which runs fine in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: jetbrains-rider

I'm trying out Rider but failing at the first hurdle. I have a solution with 2 azure function .Net 6 projects and these run fine in visual studio for Mac, when I load them in rider and try and run one I get:

```
A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.dylib' required to execute the application was not found in ...
```

Of course I could go and try and find libhostpolicy.dylib but I'm reluctant as this runs fine in Visual studio for Mac and I need it to continue to do so. I can't understand why it runs fine in VS but not in Rider. I don't really want to be changing config when it runs in vs for Mac.

Any ideas?

Thanks